# Appcelerator titanium navigationWindow

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

Hello titanium mobiles developpers,

I have some questions about navigationWindow, because picture is better than thousands of words :

[image: Appcelerator navigation window image]

As you can see i have a blue back button of the navigationWindow and as content a ScrollableView with image :

```
<Alloy>
<Window>
    <ScrollableView id="scrollableView" showPagingControl="true" overlayEnabled="true" pagingControlColor="transparent" backgroundColor="black">
        <View id="view1">
            <ImageView class="fullBgImage"image="images/pubs/v2.png" />
        </View>
        <View id="view2">
            <ImageView id="imageview_1" image="images/pubs/pub_un.jpg" />
        </View>
        <View id="view3">
            <ImageView id="imageview_2" image="images/pubs/pub_deux.jpg" />
        </View>
        <View id="view4">
            <ImageView image="images/pubs/guide.png" />
        </View>
        <View id="view5" >
            <ImageView touchEnabled="false" image="images/pubs/start.png" />
        </View>
    </ScrollableView>
</Window>
```

My issue is that i cannot get the back button text and arrow to white color, and i get padding on both side of ScrollableView.

How can i get rid of those paddings? and color back button ?

**ABOVE QUESTIONS ARE RESOLVED BELOW**

I just have another question, is it possible to make fullscreen the imageview, i mean putting the back button under the view, please see screenshot below :

[image: How to make image under back button]

Thank you for helps.

Comment: Please do not edit your answered questions to ask something else. Instead, ask a new question in those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For back button title color,

Use **[tintColor property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow-property-tintColor)** on NavigationWindow which contain that window as :

```
    <NavigationWindow platform="ios" tintColor="white">
        <Window    </Window>
    </NavigationWindow>
```

For ScrollableView padding, I think it's due to the image aspect ratio that original width of image is the one you are viewing.

You can check it by giving some backgroundColor to the views (id="view1" or view2 or view3...) containing your images.

So, to fill entire width of screen with image, you can try 2 options:

1. Use a different aspect ratio for image (might not be work on all devices).
2. Give images **width='100%' and height='100%'** instead of **Ti.UI.FILL** or **Ti.UI.SIZE**

Here's how you can do it.

```
<View id="view1">
    <ImageView class="fullBgImage" width='100%' height='100%' image="images/pubs/v2.png" />
</View>
```

or

```
<View id="view1">
    <ImageView id='images' image="images/pubs/v2.png" />
</View>

$.images.height = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
$.images.width = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
```

Simply put, do not leave width or height auto-set. Set them yourself.

For back button behind imageview, you can do it this way:

**.xml**

```
<Window class="full-window">
   <View class='header'>
       <Button left="15" title="<  Back" color="white"></Button>
   </View>

   <View zIndex="1">
       <ScrollableView id="scrollableView" showPagingControl="true" overlayEnabled="true" pagingControlColor="transparent" backgroundColor="black">
           ....
        </ScrollableView>
   </View>
</Window>
```

**.tss**

```
".full-window": {
    fullscreen: true, // set to false if you want to show battery-signal status bar
    navBarHidden: true  // must be true to show manual view
}

".header": {
    top : 0,
    height: '64dp',
    backgroundColor: "#3000",
    zIndex : 2    // necessary to put your content view behind it
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for you helps, tintColor works fine and yes i added backgroundColor to the view and this fills entire screen but image not, so you're right it's because of image proportion.
But event i set image view width to "Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth" the width is still not fill all device width, same as width to 100%.

Comment: You need to set width and height both because if either width/height is set, then other property will be auto-calculated based on image aspect ratio.

Comment: I have added further answer. Please check and let us know the result.

Comment: Hello thank you, it's working great, i have just a least question, i updated above post

Comment: For your new question, there's only 1 way to do that. Set navbarHidden to false on that Window and create a manual Ti.UI.View of height 64dp from top=0 and add a button on left edge into it. See my updated answer.

Comment: @user44321 : :You seem to be confused with your question, it would be better if you be consistent in marking an answer as **correct answer**. You have a good luck that stackoverflow does not provide any kind of action that can be taken again you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To make it fullscreen you just need to set two Boolean properties `navBarHidden` and `fullscreen` to `true` have look on the below code :

```
<Window navBarHidden = "true" fullscreen="true">
  // Your other Views
</Window>
```

**Good Luck, Cheers**

Comment: Thanks, you're a boss.

Comment: @user44321 And how will you now show Back button? Did you even try this solution? And I would like to advise you to use separate question when you are going to unmark an already accepted answer for a different topic because when some other users will now visit this question then they will get confused how this answer solved your both issues.